# Selenium python, Using Select() select_by_value(), to search if the string contains

Tags: python, selenium, select

I am trying to use `Select()` to `find an element` in a dropdown box. But I want to enter a partial text and let it search if the element contains it

Python

```
thisValue= 1875
thisElemenet = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('id_asset'))
thisElemenet.select_by_value(str(thisValue))
```

My select script

```
<select name="asset" class="form-control" id="id_asset">
  <option value="" selected="">---------</option>

  <option value="235">UN-POA-1875 (15) | Bærbar | Lenovo L590 20Q7 i5-8265U 1.6 GHz 8 GB 256 SSD</option>

  <option value="221">UN-POA-1929 (01) | Bærbar | Lenovo L490 20Q5 Core i5 8GB 256GB SSD</option>

</select>
```

If I am searching for 1875 I want it to find the first option.

Comment: Is it possible to solve with another way? Instead of using `Select`.

Comment: Doesn't have to be  Select() that I need to use. I just need to Selenium to slect the  first option if I search for 1875

Comment: What do you mean if you search for  ? also in select you are passing `id_location`  where the id is `id_asset`.

Comment: fixed the id_asset error. What I mean is the text in one of the options contains 1875. I want to be able to select that element by passing the string 1875

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Select`, try using below xpath:

```
//select[@id="id_asset"]//option[contains(text(), "1875")]
```

Please try the following code:

```
thisValue = 1875
thisElemenet = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="id_asset"]//option[contains(text(), "{}")]'.format(thisValue))
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", thisElemenet)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use select with `id_asset` to locate the drop down.

and then  you can use

```
select#id_asset option
```

`CSS_SELECTOR` to locate all the options inside the drop down. Then iterate the drop down, and look for each `options (text)` for this example it would be `UN-POA-1875 (15) | Bærbar | Lenovo L590 20Q7 i5-8265U 1.6 GHz 8 GB 256 SSD` for the first option, and then put if condition that if it contains the desired text, select it.

```
select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_asset"))
all_options = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#id_asset option")
for option in all_options:
    if "1875" in option.text:
       select.select_by_value(option.get_attribute('value'))
```

also if in your question

```
str(thisValue)
```

represent 1875, you could replace the above line

```
if "1875" in option.text:
```

to

```
if str(thisValue) in option.text:
```